a recursion error but i do not have recursion
i have a client-server architecture game. it's designed with swing GUI, i have a problem in the game class, the class is supposed to show the 3 players' names and scores, each time a player answers it should update the jLabel for that player
i wrote this code to update the label for the player who answered correct;y but it gave me an error:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
i asked and turned out to be an infinite recursion error but i don't have any recursive methods in my codes nor have i called one, the error disappears when i delete this part of code (the SUBMITWORD method) but i can't do this since it's an important functionality.
i would be glad if someone could figure out the issue
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError at
java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:524)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:554)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:428)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:393)
 at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:180)
 at com.mycompany.wordsgame.Game.<init>(Game.java:34)
 at com.mycompany.wordsgame.WaitingRoom.<init>(WaitingRoom.java:23)

here's the code:
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Game extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public String s1 = "aufiojdnble";
    public String s2 = "gfyrhebdsho";
    Info info = new Info();
    public int correctAnswersCount = 0;
    public int player1ans = 0;
    public int player2ans = 0;
    public int player3ans = 0;
    public Server server ;
    public String currentString;
    public List<String> predefinedWordsS1 = List.of("found", "bad", "lion", "audio", "fun","job", "no", "bold", "bad", "no", "food", "blonde", "noble");
    public List<String> predefinedWordsS2 = List.of("dog", "boy", "good", "her", "red", "hey", "yes", "fry", "hero", "shy", "bed", "shore", "body", "shoes");


    public Game() {
        initComponents();
        displayLetters();
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public void updatePlayerLabels(String[] playerNames) {
    // System.out.println("Received player list from server: " + Arrays.toString(playerNames));

        if (playerNames.length >= 1) {
            jLabel4.setText(playerNames[0]);
        }
        if (playerNames.length >= 2) {
            jLabel5.setText(playerNames[1]);
        }
        if (playerNames.length >= 3) {
            jLabel6.setText(playerNames[2]);
        }
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public void displayLetters() { // works
    currentString = wordSequence();
    jLabel2.setText(currentString);
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public String wordSequence() { // works
        // Generate a random number (0 or 1)
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(2);
        return (randomNumber == 0) ? s1 : s2;
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public void submitWord(String word) {
    if (isValidWord(word, currentString)) {
        correctAnswersCount++;
        String name = info.getUsername();
        String player1 = jLabel4.getText();
        String player2 = jLabel5.getText();
        String player3 = jLabel6.getText();
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(player1)) {
            player1ans++;
            jLabel13.setText(String.valueOf(player1ans));
            if (player1ans == 5) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulations! " + player1 + " has won the game!");
            }
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(player2)) {
            player2ans++;
            jLabel14.setText(String.valueOf(player2ans));
            if (player2ans == 5) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulations! " + player2 + " has won the game!");
            }
        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(player3)) {
            player3ans++;
            jLabel15.setText(String.valueOf(player3ans));
            if (player3ans == 5) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulations! " + player3 + " has won the game!");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid word. Please try again.");
        }
        jTextField1.setText("");
    }
}

    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    public boolean isValidWord(String word, String currentString) { // works
    // Get the list of predefined words based on the currently displayed string
    List<String> predefinedWords;
    if (currentString.equals(s1)) {
        predefinedWords = predefinedWordsS1;
    } else if (currentString.equals(s2)) {
        predefinedWords = predefinedWordsS2;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    // Check if the entered word is in the list of predefined words
    return predefinedWords.contains(word);
    }

    private void initializeComponents() {
    initComponents();
    jLabel4.setText("");
    jLabel5.setText("");
    jLabel6.setText("");
}


probably seeing the stack trace, at least the repeating lines of it, and having a [mre] would help understand the problem

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:524)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.(Window.java:554)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:428)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:393)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:180)
at com.mycompany.wordsgame.Game.(Game.java:34)
at com.mycompany.wordsgame.WaitingRoom.(WaitingRoom.java:23)

First, [edit] your post and add the stack trace (format as code) there instead of in a comment.  Second, unless you removed a large number of entries from the stack trace, that doesn't look like a recursion error... How much memory did you allocate to the stack?

i removed a LOT from the stack trace to fit in the comment, it has so many lines even chatGPT can't generate a response when i sent the trace. how do i check how much memory i've allocated?

an infinite recursive call usually means a repetition in the Stack Trace - the posted one does not show that, most probably the important part - the repetition - was not posted (example : Game creating a new WaitingRoom and WaitingRoom creating a new Game - so we would see repetition of the last two entries of the posted trace [just a guess/example]) || Also how you know it "turned out to be an infinite recursion error"?
